# Trying to print properties of stdClass object in Php starting with literal '$'

Tags: php, echo, stdclass

My object name is $distinct1

`print_r($distinct1)` shows the object below but when I try to do

```
echo $distinct1->properties->city
```

OR

```
echo $distinct1->distinct_id
```

I don't get any value return. Any idea whats going on?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [$distinct_id] => AAA
    [$properties] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$city] => Palo Alto
            [$country_code] => US
            [$region] => California
            [$name] => John Smith
)
)
```

Comment: Uhhh is your field named `'properties'` or `'$properties'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, if your properties are really named like that:

```
$distinct1->{'$properties'}->{'$city'}
```

But if possible, I'd look into the mechanism that *sets* it like that & fix it there.

Answer (score 1):

The property names of that object actually start with `$` for whatever weird reason.

```
echo $distinct1->{'$properties'}->{'$city'};
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I am pulling data from a third party API and don't know why they used $ before the property name.